# How to get tweets of a year for data mining using twitter API

Tags: twitter4j

I like to retrieve 2014-2015 tweets based on some search key for data mining.
I am using  twitter4j(java) and  calling API GET search/tweets.I am getting only last week tweets.Can anyone please suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 1):

[gnip](https://gnip.com/)

You got to pay for data older than about a week.

Answer (score 0):

Via Gnip, you can order a one-time data pull (called a Historical PowerTrack One-Time Job).  You provide the rule, and a data file will be sent back to you with download directions.

You can learn more about Historical PowerTrack [here](http://bit.do/GSWHPT) and [here](http://support.gnip.com/apis/historical_api/)